# How to jump out of quote or jump out of code block with vim in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim

I'm learning Vim for few days and I have a question when coding with vim.

Let say I'm creating an object like this

```
const person = {
  name: "Tu<my pointer after u character>"
}
```

What is the best way to move my pointer from after `u` character to after the double quote so I can keep writing my object

Another case is if I finish create object like this

```
const person = {
  name: "Tu<my pointer after u character>"
}
```

How do I get my pointer to the line after the close curly bracket to keep writing code.

Some people say that I can escape the insert mode and using `shift + A` to go end of line but it takes 4 buttons to do that?

Thanks for answering my question.

Comment: Better suited for [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I see, Do I need to delete this post?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the way to do it is to escape insert mode and use <kbd>A</kbd> to
[A]ppend stuff to the end of the line. To jump to the `}` in your code, there
are many many options, and which to use depends on the situation and user
preference, but I tend to use something like `3j` to move 3 lines down (or
however many I need to move). And by putting the following in my vimrc:

```
set number
set relativenumber
```

I always know what number of lines I want to move.

Vim seems a bit weird for about 2 weeks (for me at least, when I started coding
in Vim) but after that it becomes automatic that if I finish inserting text for
any reason, I instinctively hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>. Many (most?) vim users remap
the some other key like <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to act like <kbd>Esc</kbd>, since the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key on
modern keyboards is in an awkward position (unlike in the early days).

Once the 'modal' nature of vim becomes natural for you, things will fall into
place.

Oh, and it really helps if you learn to touch type 100% (i.e. **never** need to
look at the keyboard - even for numbers, punctuation, 'weird symbols' etc.)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, press `<Right>` or `<End>`, *just like in any editor*.

In the second case, press `<Down>` to move the caret after the `}`, then press `<CR>` (to open a new line) or `<Down>` (to move the caret to the line after the `}`), *just like in any editor*.

Going back to normal mode just for that is silly.

---

Note that you wouldn't have to deal with this without whatever you installed that closes quotes automatically.

Comment: the <End> <Down> buttons seem pretty far for me. For the second case, I found another solution is pressed `Ctrl + Shift + \`. Anyway, thanks for answering me.

Comment: Yeah, giant keyboards are a pain.